# Data fetched in Client Component not showing in Nexjs 14 when deployed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I am using Nextjs 14 client component to fetch and render data from my headless wordpress cms, this works in my local environment, however, when I deployed the app on aws amplify. The data does not show. Please i would like to know why this is happening and to know a better oh handling this. Here is my code below.

```
'use client'

function Faqs() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [activeState, setActiveState] = useState({ title: null, index: null });
  const [isSearchPerformed, setIsSearchPerformed] = useState(false);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchWords, setSearchWords] = useState([]);

  const searchResultsRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getFaqData() {
      let receivedData = await getFaqs();
      console.log(receivedData);

      const flattenData = receivedData.flatMap((edge) =>
        edge.node.cta.questionAndAnswer.map((qa) => ({
          id: `${edge.node.id}`,
          title: edge.node.title,
          question: qa.question,
          answer: qa.answer,
        }))
      );
      console.log(flattenData);
      const newSearch = new JsSearch.Search("id");
      newSearch.indexStrategy = new JsSearch.PrefixIndexStrategy();
      newSearch.sanitizer = new JsSearch.LowerCaseSanitizer();
      newSearch.searchIndex = new JsSearch.TfIdfSearchIndex("id");

      // Add indices and documents
      newSearch.addIndex("question");
      newSearch.addIndex("answer");
      newSearch.addDocuments(flattenData);

      // Update state with new search instance
      setSearch(newSearch);
      setData(receivedData);
    }
    getFaqData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsSearchPerformed(false);
  }, [searchQuery]);

  const performSearch = () => {
    setIsSearchPerformed(true);
    if (searchQuery === "") {
      setSearchResults([]);
      setIsSearchPerformed(false);
    } else {
      const words = searchQuery.trim().toLowerCase().split(/\s+/);
      setSearchWords(words); // Update searchWords state

      let combinedResults = new Set();
      words.forEach((word) => {
        const results = search.search(word);
        results.forEach((result) => combinedResults.add(result));
      });

      setSearchResults(Array.from(combinedResults));

      if (searchResultsRef.current) {
        searchResultsRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
      }
    }
  };

  function highlightSearchTerm(text, searchWords) {
    let highlightedText = text;
    for (const word of searchWords) {
      if (word.trim() === "") continue;
      const escapedWord = word.replace(/[-/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&");
      highlightedText = highlightedText.replace(
        new RegExp(escapedWord, "gi"),
        (match) => `<span class="highlight">${match}</span>`
      );
    }
    return DOMPurify.sanitize(highlightedText);
  }
  console.log(searchResults, "SEARCH RESULTS");
  console.log(data, "FAQ data");
  return (
    <>
      {" "}
      <Hero
        leftContent={
          <HeroLeftComponent
            data={data}
            onSearchChange={setSearchQuery}
            onSearch={performSearch}
          />
        }
        rightContent={""}
        leftColW={"1fr"}
        rightColW={"0.2fr"}
        minHeight={"60rem"}
        bgImg={faqsBg}
        bgPosition={"50% 20%"}
      />
      <Container>
        <CustomContainer>
          <Box sx={{ margin: "3rem 0" }}>
            <HomeIcon>
              <Link href={"/faqs"}>
                {" "}
                <Typography
                  variant="body1"
                  fontSize={{ mobile: "1.6rem", portraitTab: "1.4rem" }}
                  fontWeight={"500"}
                >
                  FAQs{" "}
                </Typography>
              </Link>
            </HomeIcon>
          </Box>
          <Box ref={searchResultsRef}>
            {searchQuery !== "" && isSearchPerformed ? (
              searchResults.length > 0 ? (
                searchResults.map((item) => {
                  const highlightedQuestion = highlightSearchTerm(
                    item.question,
                    searchWords
                  );
                  const highlightedAnswer = highlightSearchTerm(
                    item.answer,
                    searchWords
                  );
                  return (
                    <Box margin={"5rem 0"}>
                      <Typography
                        variant="h3"
                        fontSize={{ mobile: "2.8rem", portraitTab: "2.4rem" }}
                        className="color-primary-light"
                        fontWeight={"500"}
                        paddingBottom={"2rem"}
                      >
                        {item.title}
                      </Typography>
                      <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        fontSize={{ mobile: "2.7rem", portraitTab: "1.8rem" }}
                        fontWeight={"600"}
                        textTransform={"capitalize"}
                        sx={{
                          cursor: "pointer",

                          "&:hover": {
                            color: "#3768b0",
                          },
                        }}
                        className={`text-midnight-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                          __html: highlightedQuestion,
                        }}
                      ></Typography>
                      <Typography
                        variant="h5"
                        fontSize={{ mobile: "1.9rem", portraitTab: "1.6rem" }}
                        fontWeight={"normal"}
                        lineHeight={"1.6"}
                        padding={"1rem 0"}
                        className={`text-midnight-blue ${openSans.className}`}
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                          __html: highlightedAnswer,
                        }}
                      ></Typography>
                    </Box>
                  );
                })
              ) : (
                <Box
                  display={"flex"}
                  height={"40vh"}
                  justifyContent={"center"}
                  alignItems={"center"}
                  className="flex min-h-[20vh] items-center justify-center"
                >
                  <Typography
                    variant="h3"
                    fontSize={{ mobile: "2.8rem", portraitTab: "2.4rem" }}
                    className="color-primary-light"
                    fontWeight={"500"}
                    paddingBottom={"2rem"}
                  >
                    No question found
                  </Typography>
                </Box>
              )
            ) : (
              <AccordionWrapper data={data} />
            )}
          </Box>
        </CustomContainer>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default Faqs;
```